# Someone or something that blocks a view

Tags: single-word-requests, metonyms

Is there a single word or metonym for someone or something that "blocks a view"?

I'm looking for a word that, unlike "obstacle" or "obstruction", conveys the "view" part.

Comment: Could you provide more context? In general, there are many words that could fit you need, e.g. a *blind*, a *cover*, a *shield*, etc.

Comment: Obstruction conveys view to me.

Comment: Agree with @RyeBread. There's a reason why some concert venues sell "obstructed view" tickets.

Comment: mother-in-law    .

Comment: @RyeBread Has it right!  Obstruction says it all.

Comment: In Swedish you can tell someone "your father was not a glass-blower!" if they are in the way. If that's interesting :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a '[blind](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/blind)?' i.e. 'something that obstructs vision'

Comment: The usages at your source seem to suggest that this word is used to convey intentional obstruction of a view, rather than, say, a tree that is in the way. Not that I have a better idea.

Comment: As a verb you could say "the tree blinds my view." But yes, "blind" as a noun has very intentional connotations (I think from hunting).

Comment: In fact, the word you're looking for is "blinder."  More often used for those flaps limiting a horse's field of view, it's applicable to humans as well.

Answer (score 1):

"**[block](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Block)**" or "**blocker**" fits to the definition.

> **block** *n*  Something that obstructs; an obstacle.
>
> **blocker** *n*  a person or thing that acts as a block

---

> **Synonyms: block, hide, obscure, obstruct, screen, shroud**
>
> These verbs mean to cut off from sight:
>
> *a tree that blocked the view; a road hidden by brush; mist that obscured the mountain peak; skyscrapers obstructing the sky; a fence that screens the alley; a face shrouded by a heavy veil.*

Answer (score 1):

You could use **occulter**. 
[The Collins dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/occulter) gives the meaning as:

> a thing that occults, screens or blocks out

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want to really add visual obstruction works but you could also go with **blind spot**.

Usage:  "The car merging caught me off guard because my car has a huge blind spot."

> an area where a person's view is obstructed.
>
> "the angle rearview mirror eliminates blind spots on both sides of the
>   car"

Comment: The blind spot is the thing that occurs because of the view-blocker,  is it not?

Comment: @AsianSquirrel - It is usually used as the field of vision that cannot be seen.  Now I guess some might say the "blocker" is the blind spot but that is not common usage.